# Using DLL in windows Go

Tags: winapi, go, dll

I'm trying to use proprietary DLL in my Go project.

One of DLL's method description looks like this:

```
BYTE*   Init(const BYTE* path, int id);
```

in my test Go project I'm doing something like:

```
import (
  "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

var (
  lib = windows.MustLoadDLL("dllname.dll")
  init = lib.MustFindProc("Init")
)

func main() {
  path := "some"
  bytePath = []byte(path)

  init.Call(
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&bytePath)),
    uintptr(9)
  )
}
```

Library gets called, there is an error message "path isn't exist", but I think that type of my path is not right. That's why library can't see the folder.

Maybe there is a better way of doing this? Maybe it's a bad case of Go usage and I should find some package or even language?

Comment: I highly doubt the error says "path isn't exist", because that's grammatically incorrect. Can you paste the _exact_ error?

Comment: Not sure why you though that [tag:c#] is related to this question, so I removed it. Please only add tags relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: @Flimzy yeah, that was just example. Also name of dll is not a 'dllname.dll' ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your path likely needs to be NUL terminated:

```
import (
  "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

var (
  lib = windows.MustLoadDLL("dllname.dll")
  init = lib.MustFindProc("Init")
)

func main() {
  path := "some"
  bytePath = []byte(path + "\x00")

  init.Call(
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&bytePath[0])),
    uintptr(9)
  )
}
```

Comment: Why do you use &bytePath[0] ? I tried to make a NULL terminated path, but i don't know about [0]. I mean, it works! Thank you! But what is [0] and where can i read about this?

Comment: @MrTwister It's because of difference between Go strings and what Windows want. Go string is (somewhat) a length + pointer to byte array. Windows (i.e. C string) want a byte array ending in NULL (character with 0 code). `bytePath[0]` is the first letter of byte array.

Comment: @ArmanOrdookhani yes, i know about NULL character and [0] is the first element :) Surprise for me is that i need to use this first element of pointer instead of just &bytePath.

Comment: I would add a couple of assorted ideas: 1) The "golang.org/x/sys/windows" is not needed; just import "syscall" which, on Windows, contains all those `MustLoadDLL` et al; 2) The approach with `[]byte(path…` only works for pathnames which are composed solely of 7-bit-clean (that is, US-ASCII) characters which is not too interesting in the present days of globalization. If this property of the paths can be guaranteed (i.e., the code will only run in a sufficiently controlled environment), that's OK; otherwise one should supposedly first convert the pathname to the active system's "code page".

Comment: The latter can be done by calling [`kernel32!GetACP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318070) and then using it with `golang.org/x/text/encoding` (and its `charmap` subpackage). The result of the conversion can then be NUL-terminated and supplied down to the call of that DLL's function.

Comment: To expand on my first note, [the strings in Go are assumed do be encoded in UTF-8](https://blog.golang.org/strings), and type-converting them to `[]byte` would only be semantically correct if either the DLL indeed expects UTF-8-encoded pathnames (which would be very weird for Windows-specific code) or the source string only contains 7-bit characters which are encoded using a single byte each—as opposed to other Unicode characters which end up encoded with 2 or more bytes eac in UTF-8.